# Stop getting location updates in background iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios-background-mode

I am making an app for tracking a user locations but I am facing a problem to track continuous user location in background until user stop by themselves.I myself test the app by tracking in car of distance of 17 kilometer in a time of around 30 miniutes. When I started the tracking I just simply put the App in background and when I reached the destination I saw that App stopped updating location when I completed a distance of around 10-12 kilometer and time of around 15-20 minutes.It is like IOS suspend the app in background.I tested the App in iOS version of 12.following are the screen shots for what I have done for getting locations:[image: Location manager]
[image: Background mode in capabilities]
[image: info.plist file]

I am using standard location service.what should I do now to get continuous location update in background with this level of accuracy?

Comment: Did the user grant the required permissions?

Comment: yes @Sudara I have set both keys i.e "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" and "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description".When I test the App I have authorized the App "Always allow location".